# resize javascript error in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, resize

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
self.setDimensions();
});
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'on'**

Why is only google chrome throwing this error?
and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use event delegation (`on`) here. Just bind the `resize` event directly to the window:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  self.setDimensions();
});
```

I could replicate your error when using an older version of jQuery (1.6.4).

- [Working (1.8.2)](http://jsfiddle.net/P89T4/3/)
- [Working (1.7.2)](http://jsfiddle.net/P89T4/4/)
- [Not Working (1.6.4)](http://jsfiddle.net/P89T4/5)

Try to make sure you're using a recent version of jQuery and not an older, perhaps cached version.

Comment: I tried it but I don't know if it works right, but the console shows no more error in this spot, however theres similar errors
    self.$window.on('scroll', function(){
    self.scrollEvent();
**Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'**

Do I go about fixing it the same way?

Comment: would you also incidentally know why chrome is playing hard to get and (on) won't work with it, when it seems to work with every other browser?
Btw, Thanks for the answer :D

Comment: @KellyHarrison To your first question: [Yes, you can](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/). See updated answer.

Comment: I believe I used 1.7.1
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
and it still doesn't work

Comment: thank you so much!
I switched to 1.8.3 and everything runs beautifully!